# Elastic Beanstalk + AWS::RDS::DBInstance = InvalidParameterValue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a working elastic beanstalk environment, which is launched by boto3. Unfortunately, when I tried to launch an RDS instance with the environment, it fails and terminates with the error `InvalidParameterValue: null`, but no indication which parameter is invalid.

The only thing I changed was adding the file `01_rds.config` to `.ebextensions`:

```
Resources:
    AWSEBRDSDatabase:
        Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
        Properties:
            AllocatedStorage: 5
            CopyTagsToSnapshot: true
            DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
            DBSnapshotIdentifier: arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:snapshot:env-qa-seed
            DBSubnetGroupName: "env-qa-staging"
```

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-masterusername), this should be all I need.

I also tried with these additional properties, with the same result:

```
DBInstanceIdentifier: env-db
DBName: site   
Engine: MySQL
EngineVersion: 5.6.19b
PubliclyAccessible: false
MasterUsername: dbuser
MasterUserPassword: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```